# Floppy Drive clicking problem

Tags: floppy

After installing drivers for samsung phone ("Kies" from samsung vebsite), the floppy drive started to clicking when windows is on. This is not my computer. So what can be the problem?

Comment: Do they really need a floppy drive? can you just remove it? That seems to be more practical than actually troubleshooting this particular case.

Comment: Not my PC, something with floppy because when pc boots all ok, after windows starts and all background app started to work, starts clickin sound

Comment: I found the program VIAService was something doing with PC

Comment: It was from samsung driver folder, i deleted, will pc run norm,ally with out it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to guess I'd say the software's trying to monitor the drive for new media.  You could probably disable it from the BIOS or device manager if you like.

Comment: No prob, I guess a lot of new software is designed without the floppy drive in mind ;-)

Comment: @Col: The audacity!!

Comment: @surfasb What can I say, I'm old enough to remember when computers had nothing except floppy drives but times change.

Comment: Aye. A lot of management tools still force you to use a floppy.

Answer (score 0):

Just stop CDMA Device service!